# Simple Replace \ with *

Tags: jquery

I have a paragraph that currently has C:\

How can I use jQuery to change it to be C:*

Comment: Google "javascript string replace".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful! JavaScript's `string.replace` doesn't behave the same as other languages. It will only replace one occurrence of the matched string. If you want to do a global search-and-replace you have to use a RegExp object so you can set the `g` flag:

```
el.text(el.text().replace(/C:\\/g, 'C:*'));
```

An alternative to regexcersizing the replace operation (especially useful when you have an arbitrary string to replace that might contain regex-special characters), is the JS split-and-join replacement idiom:

```
el.text(el.text().split('C:\\').join('C:*'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var para = $("p"); //Get your paragraph
para.text(para.text().replace(/C:\/gi, "C:*");
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple:

```
var p = $("#theparagraph");
p.text(p.text().replace("C:\\", "C:*"));
```

Comment: What if I needed to change more than one \??

Comment: @Bruno: ask precise questions, this answer is correct as per your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript replace function:

```
var s= 'C:\\';
s= s.replace('C:\\', 'C:*');
alert(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery 1.4, you can pass a function into any setter function to manipulate it's value.

```
jQuery('p').text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace(/C:\\/g, 'C:*');
});
```